# Generic implementation should return subtype depending on subclass

Tags: scala, generics, inheritance, polymorphism, return-type

In my application there are Resources and many of these are loaded the same way, so I wanted to abstract the methods.

I created a trait called `Resources`

Now this trait has three tasks to fulfill.

1. It implements a Cache for an arbitrary amount of `Resource`s.
2. It implements a Map for all the loaders that can load Resources of that type. (E.g. for Resource Images that may hold a "PNGLoader", a "JPGLoader" or even a "GIFLoader")
3. Implement generic/default methods for retrieving a Resource at a given path

It looks like this:

```
trait Resources
{
    private val loaders: mutable.HashMap[String, ResourceLoader] = new mutable.HashMap[String, ResourceLoader]
    private val cache: mutable.HashMap[String, Resource] = new mutable.HashMap[String, Resource]

    def get(path: String): Resource =
    {
        // Check cache... if fail, see if there is a loader registered
    }

    private def load(path: String): Resource =
    {
        // Check if there is a loader for the file, if so loader.load(path)
    }

    def registerLoader(...)
}

trait ResourceLoader
{
    def load(path: String): Resource
}

trait Resource
```

Now imagine this:

```
class Image extends Resource

object Images extends Resources

object PNGLoader extends ResourceLoader
{
    Textures.register("png", this)

    override def load(path: String): Image =
    {
        // Do some magic
    }
}
```

Now, there is a problem. That approach would work (I already tried), but the thing is:

```
val img: Image = Images.get("images/test.png")
```

would lead to a type mismatch, because Image != Resource.

So I would need to do

```
val img: Resource = Images.get("images/test.png")
```

or cast it manually. Both not really an option.

Now, I tried to work with something like this:

```
trait Resources[ResourceType <: Resources[ResourceType]]
{
      private val cache: mutable.HashMap[String, ResourceType] = new mutable.HashMap[String, ResourceType]
   def get(path: String): ResourceType = {...}
}

trait ResourceLoader[ResourceType <: ResourceLoader[ResourceType]]
{
    def load(path: String): ResourceType
}
```

but of course this can't work, because although the types are named exactly the same, there is no shared information, so "ResourceType (of ResourceLoader) != ResourceType (of Resources)" so `loader.load(path)` can't work.

To **summarize**: I want to return a ConcreteType (for an ImageLoader that should be an Image, for a VideoLoader this should be a Video), but have different classes responsible for the cache, like "Images" and "Videos", so I can do:

`val video: Video = Videos.get(...)` and `val image: Image = Images.get(...)`

So there should be different caches for everything (so I can flush all the videos or all the images etc.)

Also, I just saw, that I probably need to change the **private** to **protected** *g*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed make `Resources` and `ResourceLoader` generic, but the upper bound can be simpler: `A <: Resource`.

This way you could end up with something like :

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

trait Resource

trait Resources[A <: Resource] {
  protected val cache = HashMap.empty[String, A] // protected for example below
  private val loaders = HashMap.empty[String, ResourceLoader[A]]
  def get(path: String) : A = cache.get(path).get // don't call .get on Option
  def registerLoader(loader: ResourceLoader[A]) = ???
}

trait ResourceLoader[A <: Resource] {
  def load(path: String): A
}
```

Which you could use with your `Image` resource :

```
class Image extends Resource

object Images extends Resources[Image] {
  cache += "foo" -> new Image
}

Images.get("foo")
// Image = Image@4ddf3cd9
```

You can see that the result type of `Images.get` is `Image`.

You are only able to register loaders of type `ResourceLoader[A]`, so you can safely call `loader.load(path)` since it will also return a resource of type `A`.